# Tensorflow 2 - How to apply adapted TextVectorization to a text dataset

Tags: tensorflow, word-embedding

## Question

Please help understand the cause of the error when applying the adapted [TextVectorization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/TextVectorization) to a text Dataset.

## Background

[Introduction to Keras for Engineers](https://keras.io/getting_started/intro_to_keras_for_engineers/#the-ideal-machine-learning-model-is-endtoend) has a part to apply an adapted TextVectorization layer to a text dataset.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization
training_data = np.array([["This is the 1st sample."], ["And here's the 2nd sample."]])
vectorizer = TextVectorization(output_mode="int")
vectorizer.adapt(training_data)

integer_data = vectorizer(training_data)  # <----- Apply the adapted TextVectorization
```

### Problem

Try to do the same by first adapt a TextVectorization layer to the PTB text, then apply it to the Shakespeare text.

#### Adapted a TextVectorization to PTB

```
f = "ptb.train.txt"
path_to_ptb = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    str(pathlib.Path().absolute()) + '/' + f,
    f'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tomsercu/lstm/master/data/{f}'
)

ptb_ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset(
    filenames=path_to_file, compression_type=None, buffer_size=None, num_parallel_reads=True
)\
.filter(lambda x: tf.cast(tf.strings.length(x), bool))\
.shuffle(10000)

from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization
vectorizer = TextVectorization(output_mode="int", ngrams=None)
vectorizer.adapt(ptb_ds)
```

#### Apply the TextVectorization layer to the Shakespeare text and got an error

```
path_to_shakespeare = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'shakespeare.txt', 
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/shakespeare.txt'
)

shakespeare_ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset(path_to_shakespeare)\
    .filter(lambda x: tf.cast(tf.strings.length(x), bool))

shakespeare_vector_ds =\
    vectorizer(shakespeare_ds.batch(128).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE))  <----- Error
```

### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-216442e69438> in <module>
----> 1 shakespeare_vector_ds = vectorizer(shakespeare_ds.batch(128).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE))
...
alueError: Attempt to convert a value (<PrefetchDataset shapes: (None,), types: tf.string>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.PrefetchDataset'>) to a Tensor.
```

## Solution

This works but not clear why above causes the error, although it seems to be doing the same.

- [Tensorflow Word2Vec tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word2vec)

```
shakespeare_vector_ds =\
   shakespeare_ds.batch(1024).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE).map(vectorizer).unbatch()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.data.Dataset.map` applies a function to each element (a Tensor) of a dataset.  The `__call__` method of the `TextVectorization` object expects a `Tensor`, not a `tf.data.Dataset` object. Whenever you want to apply a function to the elements of a `tf.data.Dataset`, you should use `map`.